# C# to VB.NET Code Converter

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, code-conversion

I need a C# to VB.NET code converter, and I'm willing to pay.  I want something that's ultra convenient, as I want to reduce the amount of copy/paste that I have to do... so could anybody give me some tips to what is out there?  I want processing in bulk too, and to support the latest operations (LINQ, new VB inline-function support and all).

Thanks.

Comment: Need to explain "reduce the amount of copy/paste that I have to do."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert these lines from C# to VB.Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368877/convert-these-lines-from-c-to-vb-net)

Comment: Mine is a different question, not a dup. I want a paid tool to do it in bulk... this was for a single class.

Comment: I write articles, I write a lot of C# code,  to save me hours upon hours of conversion work.  That's why.

Comment: Before buying a software try using this link. http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/ You can upload your c# files for converting them to vb.net.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have Tangible Software's Instant VB that I use.  It seams to work very well.  It will do LINQ, Full projects, files and snippets.

http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/Instant_VB.html

Answer (score 3):

Online:

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: I have been using for years with good success. Does not handle LINQ, but that is not too much of a problem.

Comment: Looks like single file only? I need something to do in bulk.  Not interested in the free ones.  converter.telerik.com has a utility to copy files in bulk, but it doesn't work.  It errors on me.

Answer (score 0):

One roundabout way to go about it is to disassemble an assembly using [RedGate's .NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/), and export the VB/C# code.

Reflector can loose some of the code flavor in the conversion/dissassembly, but I've always been able to get it to compile.

I've used several free tools online, but have found their correctness to be spotty at best. The one @Jeremy refers to is fairly decent, but lacks some recent .NET features. Odds are it will meet your needs.